# memory crash when i try to stopAnimating UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone

When ever i am trying to update the UIActivityIndicatorView from thread . the app is getting crashed by throwing an exception 
 modifying layer that is being finalized - 0x7e177fd0
-[CALayer removeAnimationForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7e177fd0 . 
when i try track the memory leaks form the mallocDebugger tool .

this crash is not happening at all the time happening 1 out of 10

please help me out rom this memory issue

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

```
[autoRechargeCell addSubview:activityIndicator];
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
   if( [PennyTalkAPI getBalanceInfoForAccount:appDelegate.accountNumber withPIN:appDelegate.pinNumber])
{   
    [autoRechargeCell.switchField setOn:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AutoRecharge"]];
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 

}
else
{
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

[pool release];
```

This is the code i have written

Comment: please post some part of ur code.

Comment: NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    [autoRechargeCell addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
       if( [PennyTalkAPI getBalanceInfoForAccount:appDelegate.accountNumber withPIN:appDelegate.pinNumber])
    {   
        [autoRechargeCell.switchField setOn:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AutoRecharge"]];
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    }
    else
    {
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }
    
    [pool release];

Comment: this is the code i have written

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at code and seeing error I assume you release your Activity Indicator and then you are trying to access it to animate..

Solution: Declare `UIActivityIndicator` object in .h file synthesize and release it in `-(void)dealloc` method.

Comment: Why would you want to synthesize it if it is only used in your one class? Just need to follow correct memory management procedures

Comment: @NickBull: Yes. Thanks for prompting. No need to synthesize just releasing it at proper time and place. :-))

Comment: I am releasing it in dealloc method only

Answer (score 0):

This is either a double release error, or a dangling pointer. You should enable zombie detection in your Scheme's configuration, and try the Zombies instrument in Instruments.

Comment: I am trying By enabling NSZombies and malloc guard . i have not released my activity indicator